# Sorbet Error - The Super class UserBase of UserEmbeds does not derive from Class

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I've been very interested in adopting `sorbet` for strict types in ruby, but while installing it on my existing codebase i've run into a wall that I dont understand

I get the following error when running `sbc tc`

```bash
entities/user_entities.rb:25: The super class CrewManagement::Entities::UserBase of CrewManagement::Entities::UserEmbeds does not derive from Class https://srb.help/5067
    25 |    class UserEmbeds < UserBase
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    entities/user_entities.rb:6: CrewManagement::Entities::UserBase defined here
     6 |    class UserBase < CrewManagement::Entities::Mongoid
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the sorbet docs say under [error 5067](https://sorbet.org/docs/error-reference#5067)

```
A class’s superclass (the Parent in class Child < Parent) must be statically resolvable to a class, not a module.
```

From what I understand, the error is saying that my `class` is not inheriting from a `class`, instead its suposedly inheriting from a `module`, but when I look at everything, i'm pretty sure everything is a `class` and that sorbet might be throwing a false positive.

###### entities/user_entities.rb

```rb
module CrewManagement
  module Entities
    ## inherits from a different file
    class UserBase < CrewManagement::Entities::Mongoid
      expose :username
      ## ...
    end
    
    ## inherits from declaration above
    class UserEmbeds < UserBase
      expose :_embedded do |record, opt|
        embeds = {}
        ## ...
        embeds
      end
    end
  end
end
```

###### config/entities.rb

```rb
module CrewManagement
  module Entities
    ## inherits from grape-entity gem
    class Mongoid < Grape::Entity
      format_with(:mongo_id, &:to_s)
      with_options(format_with: :mongo_id) do
        expose :_id, as: :id
      end
      expose :created_at
      expose :updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

I *think* its flagging the grape-entity rubygem and not my codebase, but when i look at the rubygems source code i find that `Grape::Entity` is a class
https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-entity/blob/master/lib/grape_entity/entity.rb

Is the error something that I can resolve with an RBI file declaration?

---

Runtime Details:

- OS - MacOS (Monterey) 12.5.1 (2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9)
- ruby - 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin21]
- rvm - 1.29.12
- gem sorbet-static-and-runtime - 0.5.10346
- gem tapioca - 0.10.0
- gem grape-entity - 0.10.2

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet you have a declaration in your todo.rbi file that reads `module Grape::Entity; end`?

If tapioca still can't "discover" the correct types for Grape, you will need to modify your todo.rbi manually.

Edit: I see you have tapioca already. You may need to just manually add the RBI if it didn't figure it out correctly.

Comment: looks like there is no todo.rbi, and nothing in the sorbet folder referencing Grape::Entity

Comment: Did you do the Getting Started section of Tapioca? https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca#getting-started that will generate gem RBIs etc.

Comment: I followed steps 1-3 on the getting started tutorial on the `sorbet` docs https://sorbet.org/docs/adopting

Comment: reading the tapioca tutorial it answers a few questions -- im not sure which set of docs is supposed to be the source of truth now though when it comes to getting started

Comment: I had lots of trouble with the sorbet docs getting started. Restarting and following the tapioca stuff worked much better.